# Embedded Python not finding dist-packages

Tags: python, c++, cmake

I am running an embedded python application in my c++ cmake project in Ubuntu 22.04. My python version installed is 3.10 and I have python-dev installed on my machine. My CMakeLists.txt file contains the relevant python inclusion:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.21)
project(MyPythonEmbeddedApp)

find_package(Python3 3.10 REQUIRED COMPONENTS Interpreter Development)

add_executable(my_app src/main.cpp)
target_include_directories(my_app PRIVATE ${Python_INCLUDE_DIRS})
target_link_libraries(my_app Python3:python)
```

Then in my main, I have the following:

```
#include "Python.h"
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    Py_Initialize();

    // ./ is the path to myPythonModule.py
    // Must add /usr/lib/python3.10 or can't find any base python modules in script
    // Adding location to dist-packages makes valkka-onvif found
    PySys_SetPath(L"./:/usr/lib/python3.10:/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/");

    PyObject* pythonModule = PyImport_ImportModule("myPythonModule");
    Py_DECREF(pythonModule)
    Py_Finalize();
    return 0;
}
```

The python application myPythonModule.py contains the following:

```
from valkka.onvif import OnVif, DeviceIO, DeviceManagement, getWSDLPath

class OnvifClass(OnVif):
    serial_port = []

    def __init__(self, ip="172.25.0.100", port=8000, user="", password=""):
        self.ip = ip
        self.port = port
        print("Initialized Handler")
```

I am trying to create an OnVif class in python that will get called in C++. My issues is that when creating the module in c++, I get a message from the import of OnVif.

"FATAL: you are importing valkka.onvif, but don't have zeep installed.
Please install zeep with `pip install zeep`"

It can be seen that this message is produced on the import of zeep in:
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/valkka/onvif/base.py

First, I have installed valkka-onvif using

```
sudo pip3 install valkka-onvif
```

This is purposefully installed under root and puts it in /usr/local rather than a .local directory. I have also ensured that zeep is installed in the same location as well.

```
sudo pip3 install zeep==4.0.0
```

note: installing the newest version of zeep is not compatible with the valkka-onvif library.

The above packages are found in "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/". I can see both folders in this location. I can run the python module from the command line without any issue with python3, but there must be some path variable missing when running the embedded way. Also, I can run a python script from c++ without the OnVif imported.

My question ultimately is if there is some path I need to set in c++ for embedded Python to work and how would I do this? I'd like to get the module imported without any issue. I have no problem calling python methods and creating python class instances through c++.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the answer to my question. I printed the paths in the python module when running in terminal with python3. So in python:

```
print(sys.path)
```

This showed me all paths that Python was looking in for modules. Therefore I replicated this in C++ before module initialization and right after initializing python.

```
std::string pythonPath = "./";
pythonPath += ":/usr/lib/python310.zip";
pythonPath += ":/usr/lib/python3.10";
pythonPath += ":/usr/lib/python3.10/lib-dynload";
pythonPath += ":/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages";
pythonPath += ":/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages";

std::wstring wPath = std::wstring(pythonPath.begin(), pythonPath.end());
PySys_SetPath(wPath.c_str());
```